# Reveal absolute image over multiple span backgrounds

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm working on a program that will periodically create new spans. Using only the style of said spans, how can I mask an image so that parts of the image are revealed as the background of these spans? Or is this not possible.

I've tried

```
mask-image: url("image-url.png")
```

but couldn't get it to work

Comment: Welcome to SO, please include the code that you have tried so that others can reproduce the problem. You can see more on how to ask questions at the link https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it with `background-attachment: fixed;`

It places the image relative to the viewport so no matter where the span is, its all relative to the same position.

Answer (score 0):

Not totally sure if this is what you mean.  You can use:

```
background-position: center left;
background-size: cover;
```

which will act like a mask and you can just vary the background-position using left, right, center or a percentage.

See this snippet:

```html
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    body {
      padding: 0;
      margin: 0;
    }

    .container {
      display: flex;
      height: 300px;
      flex-direction: column;
    }

    .stripe {
      grid-column: 1 / -1;
      height: 100%;
      display: grid;
      grid-gap: 0;
      grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(150px, 1fr));
    }

    .stripe span {
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      background-size: cover;
      margin: 6px;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="container">
    <div class="stripe">
      <span
        style=" background-position: center right; background-image: url('https://live.staticflickr.com/8617/16110508435_486b0eeb81_b.jpg');"></span>
      <span
        style=" background-position: center; background-image: url('https://live.staticflickr.com/8617/16110508435_486b0eeb81_b.jpg');"></span>
      <span
        style=" background-position: center left; background-image: url('https://live.staticflickr.com/8617/16110508435_486b0eeb81_b.jpg');"></span>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Almost, what I want is to see them all as one image, with the white space still being accounted for, so that all the buildings in this case would look connected.

Comment: ah ok, just remove the `margin: 6px;` in `.stripe span`?

Comment: No you can still see the seams between the images, what I mean by "white space being accounted for" I mean have the image still "continue" behind the margin. So for example, if you moved the span around the background would act like a mask, revealing the part of the image that would be there, had it just been an absolute image.